# Android WebView with suffix

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, suffix

I want to add a suffix to a ERL that loads a WebView.
For example, every URL that loads in WebView automatically gets a suffix if it doesn't have one.

```
=url + "/suffix".
```

Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: Exactly the same question I was just thinking about! How strange.

Comment: Did you found any answer for that? @PeterDavidCarter

Comment: Not yet... working on node.is elements ATM, but will be sure to share the info when I find it! Seems like it will be something simple and I'll kick myself when I find out.